# Python. BigData. Need to extract Web-Browser and OS users' preferences from cells. Best-performance method?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, bigdata

So. We have a clean dataframe that was made of messy [TSV file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxWmwAIo1D_nUUpqTU5TdDlaUHc) like that (special thanks to @unutbu):
[image]

```
chunksize = 50000    # the number of rows to be processed per iteration
dfs = []
reader = pd.read_table('data/data.tsv', sep='\t+',header=None, engine='python',
                       iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize)
for df in reader:
    df = df.stack().str.extract(r'([^=]*)=(.*)', expand=True).dropna(axis=0)
    df.columns = ['field', 'value']

    df = df.set_index('field', append=True)
    df.index = df.index.droplevel(level=1)
    df = df['value'].unstack(level=1)

    df = df.fillna('')
    df['user_vhost'] = df[['user_vhost', 'vhost', 'canonized_vhost']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
    df['user_ip'] = df[['user_ip', 'ip']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
    df.drop('vhost', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop('canonized_vhost', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop('ip', axis=1, inplace=True)
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

The 'user_agent' cell looks like:

```
user_agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
```

One thing that comes to mind is the user_agent library. How would you apply (dataframe.apply/applymap?)

```
user_agent.browser.family
```

and

```
user_agent.os.family
```

to the dataframe(s) in order to make two new separate columns (browser and os) in the DataFrame?

Comment: The jupyter notebook is probably using a different installation of python if it can't find the module

Comment: wow I reinstalled anaconda / iPython + Jupyer and now everything works fine. Now I'll rename the topic into the second question: how would you do that with a dataframe :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works, but it's pretty slow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_agent':['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36']})

# create 10.000 rows DF:
df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4)

def parse_ua_series(ua):
    p = user_agents.parse(ua)
    return pd.Series([p.browser.family, p.os.family])


def parse_ua_list(ua):
    p = user_agents.parse(ua)
    return [p.browser.family, p.os.family]
```

How to apply:

```
In [83]: df.head().user_agent.apply(parse_ua_series).rename(columns={0:'browser', 1:'os'})
Out[83]:
  browser         os
0  Chrome  Windows 7
0  Chrome  Windows 7
0  Chrome  Windows 7
0  Chrome  Windows 7
```

or

```
In [85]: df.head().user_agent.apply(parse_ua_list).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'browser', 1:'os'})
Out[85]:
  browser         os
0  Chrome  Windows 7
0  Chrome  Windows 7
0  Chrome  Windows 7
0  Chrome  Windows 7
0  Chrome  Windows 7
```

Timings:

```
In [80]: %timeit df.user_agent.apply(parse_ua_series).rename(columns={0:'browser', 1:'os'})
1 loop, best of 3: 5.83 s per loop

In [81]:

In [81]: %timeit df.user_agent.apply(parse_ua_list).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'browser', 1:'os'})
1 loop, best of 3: 5.61 s per loop

In [82]:

In [82]: %timeit df.user_agent.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(parse_ua_list(x))).rename(columns={0:'browser', 1:'os'})
1 loop, best of 3: 5.78 s per loop
```

**UPDATE:**

using only `ua_parser` will be a little bit faster:

```
def parse_ua(ua):
    p = ua_parser.user_agent_parser.Parse(ua)
    return [p.get('os').get('family'), p.get('user_agent').get('family')]

In [103]: %timeit df.user_agent.apply(parse_ua).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'browser', 1:'os'})
1 loop, best of 3: 5.28 s per loop
```

**Conclusion:**

the fastest method takes approx. 528 microseconds per row. I.e. it'll take approx. 9 minutes per 1M rows on my notebook